# Create/update labels by gtk.Container.add_with_properties and gtk.Container.child_set_property

Tags: pygtk

I'm using python to make a **gtk.window** with around 50 **gtk.label** placed on it, these label need to be update every 10/15 minutes. I choose to pack them by using a single fixed container and, in order to shorten the coding, I grouped labels' datas into a list (each item of the list is a sublist containing label's text, x & y, font family and foreground color). Well, I can easily place labels by using the following code:

```
fix = gtk.Fixed()

for i in range(48):
    lbl = gtk.Label(data[i][0])
    lbl.modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse(data[i][1]))    
    lbl.modify_font(pango.FontDescription(data[i][2]))
    fix.put(lbl, data[i][3], data[i][4])

win.add(fix)
```

but the problem comes up when I need to update labels' text, if I write:

```
for i in range(48):
    lbl.set_text(data[i][0])
```

nothing happens because it's not clear which data[i][0] has to be write to which label. So I tought I may overcome the problem by using **gtk.Container.add_with_properties** for placing labels into container and **gtk.Container.child_set_property** for their update, but I got stuck since I've not clear their usage and documentation I've found by googling is quite poor. I,ve made some try, if I write this code:

```
fix = gtk.Fixed()

for i in range(48):
    fix.add_with_properties(gtk.Label(), 'text', data[i][0] , "x", str(data[i][3]), "y", str(data[i][3]))
```

the result is **"TypeError: container does not support property `text'"** ... so I get confused if I'm manipulating the container or its child widgets ?!?
Can anybody makes me clear about the usage of **gtk.Container.add_with_properties** and **gtk.Container.child_set_property** ?!?
Besides, I Wonder if it's possible to give each label a kind of "ID" by using **gtk.Container.add_with_properties** so that I can easily recognize and update later, or there are other ways to do that  which I don't know?
Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution, I was walking a totally wrong way.

Comment: After placed the labels by using the for cicle they can be updated by another for cicle like this:
i = 0
for child in fix:
child.set_text(data[i][0])
   i = i + 1

Comment: Another approach would be to save the gtk.Label objects in a list and iterate over that list to update the labels, which may or may not make things simpler depending on the structure of your code.